# C#: How to swap the position of two winform controls

Tags: c#, winforms, collections, controls

Let's say you have two `Control`s, Alice and Bob, and you want to swap their position. By that I mean that after the swap:

- If they are living in the same `ControlCollection`, Alice should have the index of Bob and vice versa.
- If in different `ControlCollection`s, Alice should have the same index as Bob, but be in Bobs `ControlCollection` and vice versa.

How would you do this? I am a bit unsure how to best solve this because of how the `ControlCollection` methods work. For example using the `Remove` method to remove a control will change the index of all the controls coming after it in the collection. The SetChildIndex works in a similar way.

***Edit:*** The parent controls of Alice and Bob are flow layout panels. This is why I want to swap their index which will in effect swap their position in the flow layout panel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the simple case, where both controls are on the same `FlowLayoutPanel`, use the [`SetChildIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex(VS.71).aspx) method on `Controls`.

Something like this ...

```
var alphaIndex = panel.Controls.IndexOf(controlAlpha);
var betaIndex = panel.Controls.IndexOf(controlBeta);
panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(controlAlpha, betaIndex);
panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(controlBeta, alphaIndex);
```

Note: I haven't handled sequence here properly - you need to put the earlier control into place first, else when the second is moved ahead of it, the resulting index will be one too high. But that's an exercise for the reader.

For the more complex case, where the controls are on different `FlowLayoutPanel`s, the code is simpler (sequence doesn't matter so much) and more complicated (each control needs to be removed from one panel and added to the other).

Answer (score 3):

```
Control bobParent = bob.Parent;
Control aliceParent = alice.Parent;
int bobIndex = bobParent.Controls.GetChildIndex(bob);
int aliceIndex = aliceParent.Controls.GetChildIndex(alice);
bobParent.Controls.Add(alice);
aliceParent.Controls.Add(bob);
bobParent.Controls.SetChildIndex(alice, bobIndex);
aliceParent.Controls.SetChildIndex(bob, aliceIndex);
```

Probably not the shortest way, but it should work...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do exactly what you are trying to achieve. But your requirements seem strange to me : you can perfectly visually swap two controls in a form without any constraint on their respective index in their parent's `ControlCollection`.

The closest you could get would be to store your controls in a `Panel` :

- You'd have `PanelA` and `PanelB`.
- At first, `PanelA` would contain `Alice` and `PanelB` would contain `Bob`.
- When swapping, store `Bob` into `PanelA` and `Alice` into `PanelB`.

`Alice` and `Bob` would not appear directly in the `ControlCollection` though, only the `Panel`s  would.

Comment: Sorry, should have said that the panels they are in are flow layout panels. So that is why I need to swap their index to swap their visual position. Edited my question =)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbeled into something while looking into this problem. 
I found that the `Control.BringToFront()` actually changes the position in the `ControlCollection`.

So:

```
foreach(Control _control in this.Controls)
  _control.BringToFront()
```

will reverse the order in the `ControlCollection`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say you have to remove all controls from the `ControlCollection`(s) you're working with and store them into a data structure(s) that respects the order of elements (maybe a `SortedList`?).

In the first case, you'd then swap Alice and Bob **in the `SortedList`** and then re-add all the controls from the `SortedList` back into the `ControlCollection`.

The second case would be similar to the first except that you'd have 2 `SortedList`s, and you'd swap Alice and Bob between them.

Comment: The `Controls` property present on every container control isn't a simple list - it's a separate object in it's own right (Control.ControlCollection - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection(VS.71).aspx) and it provides direct support for moving things around. If you remove and re-add all the controls in the way you suggest, the UI will flicker something terrible - and the code will be **slow**.

Comment: Agreed, but it would solve his problem. I forgot that it's possible to use `SetChildIndex` in the way yopu answered, so thanks for that. :)